# how to connect alfresco with java web application

Tags: primefaces, alfresco

I have installed alfresco community edition and want to develop a web application having database connectivity.

I have developed that application using jsf, primefaces but I want to connect alfresco with my application.

Can anybody help where to start?

Comment: Depends what bit(s) of Alfresco you want to integrate with, and how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Gagravarr that much more information is needed. But a safe recommendation as a good place to start is always an industry-standard API like CMIS which will give your app the ability to perform CRUD functions against the repository. So take a look at OpenCMIS, which is the Java library available at [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org), and see if that has what you need.